# Simple Image Processing in WinRT

Tags: c#, image, windows-runtime, processing

I'm working on a WinRT app that should require some image processing. I've done something similar so far but in Java, I would like to do some simple things in WinRT app also... But I can't seem to manage my way with the API...

Long story short, I have in xaml, on my page, an `image` that obtains an image with a file picker. Then when I click a "negativate" button, the image should get negativated.

Now, the method for the negativation button, I thought to look like this :

```
private void OnNegativateButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var imageToNegativate = ImagePanel.Source as WriteableBitmap ;

        if (imageToNegativate == null) //Actually is ALWAYS null :(
        {
            //Wrong code here...
            var bitmapSource = ImagePanel.Source as BitmapSource;
            imageToNegativate = new WriteableBitmap(imageToNegativate.PixelWidth, imageToNegativate.PixelHeight);
        }
        imageToNegativate = ImageUtil.Negativate(imageToNegativate);
        ImagePanel.Source = imageToNegativate;
    }
```

This is very similar to this sample I found [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Metro-Style-lightweight-24589f50) but that sample project won't even load so I tried to open the files individually... My code is that method for negativation only there is something wrong with `wb = new WriteableBitmap(bs);` in his `if (wb==null) { ... }`.

What is the approach to take a WriteableBitmap from an `image`, do some pixel manipulation, and then set the source of the image with the new WriteableBitmap...

I'm saying about `WriteableBitmap` because my method for negativation uses one for input, does some processing and outputs it. (same type, `WriteableBitmap`.

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: So where is the error?  
I believe the WriteableBitmap do not take 2 arguments only

Comment: Where Joe White has said, I know this code is faulty but I wrote it like this to try to express my needs better. I just need to take the image from that ImagePanel, as a WriteableBitmap, do the necessary processing and then show it again with the modifications on the ImagePanel. Simple task, I did it easy in Java as I said but I am not very familiar with WinRT Api especially for Imaging...

Comment: Oops I never notice it is winRT version, i cant try the code but this maybe helpful:[set source image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsourceasync)  
The pixel buffer cant be access directly, but u can use the AsStream extension to achieve this.

Comment: [This guy](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2012/08/WriteableBitmap-Pixel-Arrays-in-CSharp-and-CPlusPlus.html) has done a good job on describing how to manipulate the pixel array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joe is right in saying what is wrong with your code, but while his answer would probably work in WPF - the constructor he mentions indeed doesn't exist in WinRT/XAML. There is in fact no way to create a WriteableBitmap from a BitmapImage and the only way to attack it is to create a WriteableBitmap from the source of your BitmapImage.

One approach then would be to create a new 1x1-sized WriteableBitmap, then use its SetSource method on the source of your BitmapImage. Since the BitmapImage.UriSource property is a Uri and WriteableBitmap.SetSource() requires a Stream - you need to play with it a bit to find or download the actual image file and open a stream to read it. My toolkit has some extension methods ([WriteableBitmap.FromBitmapImage()](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/774de4ce5f1f#WinRTXamlToolkit/Imaging/WriteableBitmapFromBitmapImageExtension.cs)) to help you with it in case your images come from your application package and you could fairly easy expand it to also work with downloaded images.

The problem is - you get some inefficiencies that way - one is that you need to open and decode the file twice (which might be slow with large images on an ARM device - been there, done that), second is that you might need to re-download the file if it came from the network and third that there is a [bug](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/f2a2348d-49b5-404c-b932-dc60ffd5828a) in WinRT/XAML that causes the UriSource property of a BitmapImage to become null if you set CacheMode of an associated Image control to BitmapCache, so you might need to track your sources separately anyway.

The best solution in many ways is to simply make sure you open the source image as a WriteableBitmap from the beginning, so you don't even have to create another bitmap if you want to change it anyway. In your case the user selects the image file, so there is only one file and it seems to have a pretty big chance of being processed afterwards so opening it as a WriteableBitmap sounds like the right thing to do.

Perhaps even if you want to keep both the original and processed version of the image - creating a new WriteableBitmap of same size and copying the pixels of the original might be faster (especially on an ARM device) than decoding a big image file twice.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is these lines of code:

```
var imageToNegativate = ImagePanel.Source as WriteableBitmap ;
if (imageToNegativate == null) //Actually is ALWAYS null :(
```

The null is telling you that `ImagePanel.Source` is *not* of type `WriteableBitmap`; your typecast failed. This is expected; the picker is going to give you something read-only, because read-only images are more performant (WinRT can do some optimizations if it knows the image's content isn't going to change). You only get a `WriteableBitmap` when you explicitly create one.

The body of your `if` block also doesn't make much sense -- you're trying to create a new, empty `WriteableBitmap` with the same size as the original image, and then you try to do an inverse-video on that *empty image.* Even if you got that far, you'd just get another empty image. You're not doing anything to keep the pixels from the original image.

You do need a `WriteableBitmap` to get access to the pixel buffer, but you need to make one that's a copy of the original image. Get rid of your cast and `if` block, and try this instead:

```
var imageToNegativate = new WriteableBitmap(ImagePanel.Source);
```

Comment: Well, to be honest I've researched a lot and already tried your answer, but I it seems the constructor for WriteableBitmap requires 2 arguments, width and height, 2 integers.... What I am doing wrong...?

Comment: I've done so more research and it seems that you're answer is correct but I don't think it can apply to my situation. The constructor with one parameter for WriteableBitmap isn't avaialable for Metro App, I have only this version : WriteableBitmap(int width, int height)... I have to do more research on how to fix this :(